# Unable to set adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, adapter

I am getting a very weird error in a very simple activity. The code is below

```
String s[];
    ListView saved_lst;
    public ListDatabaseHandler getname;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved);
        getname=new ListDatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(getname.getAllName().size()), 2000).show();
            int y=getname.getAllName().size();
            s=new String[y];
            for (int i=0;i<y/2;i++){
                s[i]=getname.getAllName().get(i);
            }


        saved_lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.savedlist);
        ArrayAdapter<String> saveadapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
        saved_lst.setAdapter(saveadapter);
    }
```

getname.getAllName returns an ArrayList of the names of all the tables in the database. I have pinpointed the problem to the last statement saved_lst.setAdapter(saveadapter);

The log cat shows that there is an uncaught exception.

What could be the reason for this not running?

Logcat

```
07-30 17:22:00.480: W/dalvikvm(5458): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.TableRow.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableRow.java:247)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:114)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
07-30 17:22:00.550: E/AndroidRuntime(5458):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
```

XML File:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/savedlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code For getAllName

```
String name= new String();
    ArrayList<String> dirArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getAllName() {
        //SQLHelper help=new SQLHelper(this, "lists.db", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = DB.rawQuery(
                "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast() ) {
             name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            if (!name.equals("android_metadata") && !name.equalsIgnoreCase("temp")) {
                dirArray.add(name);
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        DB.close();
        return dirArray;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message in your logs?

Comment: "I am getting a very weird error" - Ok, what kind of error? Post the whole logcat entry for the exception

Answer (score 0):

**NullPointerException** is caused because of **trying access a object which is null.**

getname=new ListDatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext()); is just initialized and when you are trying to get the size of  getname i.e(getname.getAllName().size();) result in NullPointerException

Varify the getAllName methods in ListDatabaseHandler Class .It will provide the Solution

Comment: added the getAllName method code to the question i checked it many time its working fine.